# Sencha hello ext example not working

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I am attempting to go through the Sencha documentation and learn the tools. But I can't seem to get the hello ext working. I have created a root directory called, "helloext". Inside I have: index.html, app.js, and an ext-4 folder (which I unzipped from "Ext JS 4 SDK").

Here's the link to the documentation: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/getting_started

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Ext</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-4/resources/css/ext-all.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-4/ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    title: 'Hello Ext',
                    html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: What does your JS console say?

Comment: @OferHaber 
Starting preview server on port 8080

Modules:
  helloext (/helloext)

2014-05-22 11:37:31.222:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.14.v20131031
2014-05-22 11:37:31.268:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a problem with your code I have added it to a JS Fiddle see here jsfiddle.net/SHnKa/.
It looks like a problem with your server settings are you trying to achieve this locally?

Comment: Yes, I am. But I'll look into that more.

Comment: Have you set up IIS on Windows if thats the OS you are using? If not look into that.

Comment: I have enable the features, so I am not sure what's going on.

Comment: If you are using sencha command then jetty is built in for a quick web server for testing.  [Command to run:](http://www.ladysign-apps.com/developer/use-the-sencha-cmd-webserver/)`sencha fs web -p 80 start -map /path/to/webroot/`